# copy file to every dir and subdir in path PHP

Tags: php, scripting, directory

I need a script to copy a file to every dir and subdir inside a specific folder.

Inside a folder called 'projects' i have several folders with several folders inside them (and so on), i need a script that checks if there is a specific file in that folder, if exist, then do nothing, if not, copy it.

I need to do this in php...

Can you help?

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: using the readdir and scandir and glob can only get to depth 1, theres virtually endless depth

Comment: Perhaps this might give you some insight? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338551/php-parse-directory-and-subdirectories-for-file-paths-and-names-of-only-jpg-imag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope this code can help you for what you want

```
$maindir=".";
mylistFolderFiles($maindir);
function mylistFolderFiles($dir){
  $file = 'example.txt';
  $ffs = scandir($dir);
  foreach($ffs as $ff){
    if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
        if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) {
            $newfile=$dir.'/'.$ff .'/'. $file ;
            if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
                echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
            }
            mylistFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
      } 
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: this only gets to depth 1, so it doesnt work, but thanks anyway

Comment: sorry I changed my code take look I think fixed subdir problem

Comment: that works like a charm, thank you so so much... (still missing the check if exist part, but that doesnt matter, file is less than 490 bytes, so overwriting doesnt impact performance at all).

Answer (score 1):

This would copy all files , all folders and its content .... from cunnrent directory to target .. using `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` and `RecursiveIteratorIterator`

```
echo "<pre>";
mkdirRecursive($target);
if (! is_writable($target)) {
    echo "You don't have permission wo write to ", $target, PHP_EOL;
}
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir));
while ( $it->valid() ) {
    if (! $it->isDot()) {
        $name = $it->key();
        $final = $target . str_replace($dir, "", $name);
        if (! mkdirRecursive(dirname($final))) {
            echo "Can Create Directory : ", dirname($final), PHP_EOL;
            continue;
        }
        if (! @copy($name, $final)) {
            echo "Can't Copy : ", dirname($final), PHP_EOL;
            continue;
        }
        echo "Copied ", basename($name), " to ", dirname($final), PHP_EOL;
    }
    $it->next();
}

function mkdirRecursive($pathname, $mode = 0777) {
    is_dir(dirname($pathname)) || mkdirRecursive(dirname($pathname), $mode);
    return is_dir($pathname) || @mkdir($pathname, $mode);
}
```