# find and list all specific extension in directories and sub-directories in php

Tags: php

below code only list files in directories and does not search sub-directories:

```
<?php
//path to directory to scan. i have included a wildcard for a sub directory
$directory = "/var/www/*/";

//get all image files with a .jpg extension.
$images = glob("" . $directory . "*.jpg");

$imgs = '';
// create array
foreach($images as $image){ $imgs[] = "$image"; }

//shuffle array
shuffle($imgs);

//select first 20 images in randomized array
$imgs = array_slice($imgs, 0, 1000);

//display images
foreach ($imgs as $img) {
    echo $img . '<br>';
}
?>
```

but How can list all specific extension (for example *.jpg) in all directories and

sub directories of a path by using PHP?

Comment: For example with a `glob()`

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338551/php-parse-directory-and-subdirectories-for-file-paths-and-names-of-only-jpg-imag?rq=1

Comment: See [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php).

Answer (score 2):

You should use a recursive function.
This can help you: 
[List all the files and folders in a Directory with PHP recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24783862/list-all-the-files-and-folders-in-a-directory-with-php-recursive-function)
Look at the answer and change it to your own needs. (wanted to help you using your own code but it's too far from the right way doing it).